# Unable to run composer install

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php

I'm trying to run composer install in my project but I have the following error

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013$43e3f41fbe30a46245103451248f688a727f076a6e90636d19a69a156c17a416.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 400 Received invalid request from Client)
```

I have tried to run composer self-update and have this error

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: Failed to enable crypto failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 with apache/php5.6.4/mysql behind a proxy.

I have tried downloading http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and updated my php.ini file with the following

```
curl.cainfo=/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
openssl.cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
openssl.capath=/etc/ssl/certs
```

Running composer diagnose returns this

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 400 Received invalid request from Client)
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking HTTP proxy: OK
Checking HTTP proxy support for request_fulluri: FAIL
Unable to assess the situation, maybe packagist.org is down (The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 400 Received invalid request from Client))
Checking HTTPS proxy support for request_fulluri: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: FAIL
You are not running the latest version
```

And finally openssl_get_cert_locations() returns

- default_cert_file: /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
- default_cert_file_env: SSL_CERT_FILE
- default_cert_dir: /usr/lib/ssl/certs
- default_cert_dir_env: SSL_CERT_DIR
- default_private_dir: /usr/lib/ssl/private
- default_default_cert_area: /usr/lib/ssl
- ini_cafile: /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
- ini_capath: /etc/ssl/certs

I'm at a total loss as to what's wrong and even more how I can debug this.

I hope there's someone out there can help me!

Answer (score 6):

same with you. and i found the way to resolve it (for window 10) on internet.
1 - go to folder
   `PATH\xampp\apache` and run makecert.bat
2 - add this script to composer.json file

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.org"
        },
        {
            "packagist": false
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me man! I spend 2 nights fetching solutions for this issue on my stupid windows 10 machine with no hope until now. I'm gonna spread your answer around the web, hope it'll help others.

Comment: :) glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most likely related to HTTPS enforcement of some sort, given that from the `composer diagnose` above, the HTTP connectivity tests failed while HTTPS test passed:

```
Checking HTTP connectivity to packagist: FAIL
...
Checking HTTP proxy support for request_fulluri: FAIL
...
Checking HTTPS proxy support for request_fulluri: OK
```

Running the below snippet (to force HTTPS on composer) solved the problem for me:

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

[Solution Source](https://laravel.io/forum/solved-issues-with-nesbotcarbon)

Answer (score 1):

If you are Linux (Ubuntu) user then execute the following commands to solve:

```
php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"

wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

sudo mv cacert.pem /usr/lib/ssl/certs/cert.pem // Note: Create the cert.pem file under certs folder if does not exist.
```

Comment: Kamlesh, can you please explain the 1st step - why check the existing location of openssl certificates if going to replace the path?
Or am I supposed to replace whatever path the php command shows with the output of wget?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to change you proxy.

http://composer-proxy.jp/

Here is a proxy from Japan. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `php composer global self-update`

Answer (score 0):

Set the proxy in environment, use this in terminal:

```
export http_proxy=<proxy>:<port>
export https_proxy=<proxy>:<port>
```

Answer (score 0):

> if linux - service iptables stop
>
> or close anti-virus ,firewall on Windows

Answer (score 0):

If nothing above works for you, try deleting the http_proxy environment variable of your system settings "Environment variables"

Answer (score 0):

try composer global self-update 1.4.1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).