# URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad URI

Tags: php, laravel, cmd, composer-php

I want to create a new laravel project via composer and I have got this error

```
 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The 'http://packagist.org/p/fideloper/proxy%249271e19129358853986ed3ca9315ced11a42439a57f49537033c3b436a6ff543.json
  ' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad URI
```

[image]

Comment: try this https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4261

Comment: Anyone using windows 10 and facing this problem, consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49147518/3317006

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question gets asked pretty frequently either here, github, or elsewhere. I'd almost say that this should be a community wiki entry. I've ran into this problem myself, as well, and here's a list of things to inspect and ensure they're not the cause (good chance one of them is the cause):

(Also, run `composer diagnose -vvv` ahead of time, then look at the list below)

1. Proxy is incorrectly configured
2. Firewall is incorrectly configured
3. Bad global environment settings (bashrc, profile, etc)
4. Outdated composer version
5. Slow/degrading network performance
6. Misconfigured git addons
7. Incorrect settings in your `hosts` file
8. SSH tunnelling misconfiguration
9. GitHub/GitLab/etc. rate limiting

**Note** This is a poor answer, and isn't a good format for SO, really.

Comment: thank you Ohgodwhy i run this command composer global require "laravel/installer" and then laravel new blog and everything is ok but i didn't know where is the problem