# Why can't I use composer to create a Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I can use `laravel new app_name` to create a Laravel project, but I can't use the `composer` way. When I tried, I got the following error:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>     The 'http://repo.packagist.org/p/fideloper/proxy%24cd38bfdf33be50279112e09e4abd2f2a540454676431630e6e55e68b727bb876.json' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad URI
>   
>   create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no
>   dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [
>   -] [package] [directory] [version]

[composer diagnose -vvv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dp6N.png)

Comment: did you installed composer on your system?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525871/url-could-not-be-accessed-http-1-1-400-bad-uri

Comment: What happens if you go to `http://repo.packagist.org/p/fideloper/proxy%24cd38bfdf33be50279112e09e4abd2f2a540454676431630e6e55e68b727bb876.json` in your browser? It loads here.

Comment: Laravel's doc are really good, have a look https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation

Comment: yes I installed composer

Comment: if I go to "http://repo.packagist.org/p/fideloper/proxy%24cd38bfdf33be50279112e09e4abd2f2a540454676431630e6e55e68b727bb876.json" >>>>This page isn’t working
If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 400

Answer (score -1):

same with you. and i found the way to resolve it (for window 10) on internet. 1 - go to folder PATH\xampp\apache and run makecert.bat 2 - add this script to composer.json file

"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.org"
        },
        {
            "packagist": false
        }
    ]