# package could not be fully loaded in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I face this case when I want to download any package in laravel 
However, the package  is downloaded 
but I don't Know if it will cause a problem in the future.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\final2>composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"
```

./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
The 'http://repo.packagist.org/p/fideloper/proxy%24de6ed8cb77cc53bdea76e3b52aa1
7a7e3cb93f816873ede7f13eba172a9059d.json' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 4
0 Bad URI

http://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was lo
ded from the local cache and may be out of date
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing laravelcollective/html (v5.5.4): Downloading (100%)
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. N
 replacement was suggested.
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files

Comment: This could be more related to your network connection, but it's not guaranteed to give u trouble.

Comment: Check this if any help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525871/url-could-not-be-accessed-http-1-1-400-bad-uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525871/url-could-not-be-accessed-http-1-1-400-bad-uri)